# Obtaining predictions specific to "NA" values from a column

Tags: r

My data looks like this:

```
     v1 v2 v3 v4     pred1    pred2
1  1908  5 10  2 10.000000  2.00000
2  1908  4 15  5 15.000000  5.00000
3  1908  8 14  4 14.000000  4.00000
4  1908  1 NA  9 11.230271  9.00000
5  1908  9 NA 14  9.942911 14.00000
6  1908  7  8 17  8.000000 17.00000
7  1908  6 NA  8  7.881931  8.00000
```

I want to extract the `preds` corresponding to a column which has NA values in. That is `pred1` was obtained using the `v3` column and I would like to extract the value `11.230271` and `9.942911` along with `7.881931` which has `NA` values in the `v3` column.

So I will end up with something like `11.230271, 9.942911, 7.881931, 7.08919` where the last value `7.08919` came from `pred2` which was built on `v4` data and has an `NA` value at `row12`.

Data:

```
data <- structure(list(v1 = c(1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 
1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 1908L, 1909L, 1909L, 1909L, 
1909L, 1909L, 1909L, 1909L, 1909L), v2 = c(5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 
7L, 6L, 2L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 8L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 2L
), v3 = c(10L, 15L, 14L, NA, NA, 8L, NA, 7L, 5L, 2L, 16L, 13L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 9L), v4 = c(2L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 14L, 
17L, 8L, 18L, 16L, 15L, 11L, NA, 3L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 7L, 
6L), pred1 = c(10, 15, 14, 11.2302713507484, 9.94291143314257, 
8, 7.88193139599341, 7, 5, 2, 16, 13, 10, 11, 12, 1, 3, 4, 6, 
9), pred2 = c(2, 5, 4, 9, 14, 17, 8, 18, 16, 15, 11, 7.0891904140478, 
3, 1, 1, 10, 12, 13, 7, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `subset` the columns of interest by filtering based on another column

```
subset(data, is.na(v3), select = c("pred1", "pred2"))
```

---

If we need the values for corresponding `NA` elements in 'v3', 'v4'

```
out <- Map(function(x, y) y[is.na(x)], data[3:4], data[5:6])
out
#$v3
#[1] 11.230271  9.942911  7.881931

#$v4
#[1] 7.08919
```

then, get the values as a single `vector` by `unlist`ting

```
unlist(out, use.names = FALSE)
```

---

Or using `map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map2(data[3:4], data[5:6], ~ keep(.y, is.na(.x)))
```